# How do the following set of rewrite rules work for the HTTP authorization compared to the first set?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, server

In the guide for setting up REST API it said you may need to use the following in the htaccess for the REST API to work:

```
RewriteRule .* - [E=REMOTE_USER:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

That didn't work.

After further research I've found the following and this does work:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]
```

The second block of rewrite rules looks like it's matching the opposite of the first.

I'm familiar with RegExp but I don't know what is going on here. What are the rewrite rules doing? Why does the second set work while the first does not (but says it does)?

Answer (score 1):

`-` in the substitution part of a RewriteRule means, there will be no actual rewriting of the URL performed here, but it allows you to do additional stuff - like f.e. set an environment variable.

There is not much difference here in what happens in both versions.

The first one uses the request variable `%{HTTP:Authorization}` directly to access the value it wants to assign to an environment variable in the rule, the second version makes a “detour” by first *capturing* the full content of that variable in a RewriterCond, so that it can then be referred to in the rule with `%1`. That detour is not technically necessary though.

The main, *significant* difference between both versions here is the *name* of the environment variable that is created - the first version uses `REMOTE_USER`, the second one uses the same name for the environment variable, that the request variable already had, `HTTP_AUTHORIZATION`.

Which of those two “works” for your actual requirement here, depends on what environment variable name your Rest API *expects* to get the HTTP auth information passed under. If you match that to the actual need, then both should be interchangable.